# How do I change project title in Source Control VSCode (multi-root workspace)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I change these titles in Source Control (Git) so that I'm not confused every time?

I'm using a multi-root workspace, and as a company, we have this structure where each project is in the `clone` directory.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured this out already, but in your workspace settings file `*.code-workspace` add a "name" attribute for your folder.

```json
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "name": "Cool Project",
            "path": "../../.."
        },
        ...
```